# Get prop that passed from child component

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an react native app where I render map in App.js and this is the states of App.js:

```
this.state = {
      region: null,
      shops: [
        {
          name: "name",
          rating: 0,
          coords: {
            latitude: 543543,
            longitude: 656546
          }
        }
      ]
    };
```

and this is the render code of it:

```
 render() {
    const { region, shops } = this.state;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Map region={region} places={shops} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

as you can see I pass the shops state to Map component and in map component I have this main render to render the MapView:

```
render() {
    const region = this.props.region;
    return (
      <MapView
        style={styles.container}
        region={region}
        showsUserLocation
        showsMyLocationButton
      >
        {this.renderMarkers()}
      </MapView>
    );
```

you can see the this.renderMarkers() where the markers of shops exist:

```
renderMarkers() {
    return this.props.places.map((marker, i) => (
      <Marker key={i} title={marker.name} coordinate={marker.coords} >
        <View style={{
          flexDirection: 'row', width: 70, height: 60,
          backgroundColor: 'none',
        }}>
          <Svg
            width={60} height={50}>
            <Image
              href={require('icon.png')}
            />

            <Rating rating={marker.rating} />

          </Svg>
        </View>

      </Marker>
    ));
  }
```

each marker contain Image and Rating components and what I'm trying to do it to pass the rating like this: rating={marker.rating} to the component of Rating

now in the Rating component I'm trying to get the rating like this:

```
render() {
        let ratings = this.props.places;
        let stars = [];

        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            if (i > ratings.rating) {
// do something
            }

        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                { stars }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

now you understand that I pass the whole object of states from App component to Map component then I want to pass only the rating prop from Map component to Rating component
how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say Rating component do you mean `<Star>` component?
I noticed that in the last piece of code, which I think belongs to `<Star>` component, you try to access its props uncorrectly.
If you use

```
<Star rating = { marker.rating } />
```

then you're supposed to get that `rating` prop in `Star` component like:

```
const { rating } = this.props;
```

Comment: yees tha's what I mean sorry for that mistake I edit it and it work perfectly thanks a lot @Milore